# Check which array elements have null value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays

I have the following array.

```
var arrayNames = [ null, 'data', null];
```

I want to check which position in the array is null. for ex above, array element [0] and [2] are null,

so at the output, i need 1,2 to be assigned to a variable 'nullValues'
Can someone please let me know how to achieve this. might be very simple and i am stupid enough not to get it. any help is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#reduce` to get only the indexes of elements with `null` value.

```js
let arrayNames = [null, 'data', null];

let nullValues = arrayNames.reduce((s, a, i) => {
  if (a == null) {
    s.push(i);
  }
  return s;
}, []);

console.log(nullValues);
```

Comment: this doesn't run

Comment: @mmenschig It works fine for me, just click `run code snippet` to see the results.

Comment: I was going to suggest `filter`, but your answer is better :) ^^

Comment: @all, odd, it works but at the same time i am getting a script error notification. `[0,2]` is correct though.

Comment: @Kinduser Nevermind. I read it for the 20th time and finally understood. I'm an idiot. Hahah

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace the comment with whatever you want to do on null.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayNames.length; i++) {
    if (arrayNames[i] === null) {
        // Do stuff for index i
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayNames = [ null, 'data', null];
var nullValues = []
arrayNames.forEach(function(item, index) {
  if (item === null) {
    nullValues.push(index);
  }
});

console.log(nullValues) // [0, 2]
```

This assumes you're targeting browsers with access to Array.forEach().  If you don't have that, then

```
var arrayNames = [ null, 'data', null];
var nullValues = []
for (var i = 0; i < arrayNames.length; i++) {
  if (arrayNames[i] === null) {
    nullValues.push(i);
  }
};

console.log(nullValues) // [0, 2]
```